# Coldfusion application log repeated error with no file or error, is this a concern?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-administrator

We get this message repeatedly in our Coldfusion application log, and are wondering if it is something we should look into more or ignore.  I've googled but I can't seem to find anyone reporting this same blank-ish error.

```
'' The specific sequence of files included or processed is: ''''
```

That's it!  No file name, no error listed.  It happened 60 times in the last 2 weeks, and has been going on for as long as we can remember.  We've looked at the times / dates and there doesn't seem to be any clear pattern.  No rhyme or reason to when this error occurs.

Does anyone have any idea what this message could mean?  Is it a concern or just something to ignore in the logs?

**Edited to add requested info**

Version is Coldfusion 10
Windows Server 2008
Not sure of JVM but I'll ask our IT people

Below are a couple of times it happened with the surrounding errors... (file paths edited out)

```
6/23/2014   1:18:24     Variable VEHID is undefined. The specific sequence of files included or processed is: F:\...\ProcessNewRequest.cfm, line: 797 
6/23/2014   1:56:05     '' The specific sequence of files included or processed is: '''' 
6/23/2014   2:13:25     20,64 is an invalid date or time string. The specific sequence of files included or processed is: F:\...\testRequestAct.cfm, line: 115 


6/25/2014   0:30:33     Element REQUESTORCDSID is undefined in RECINFO. The specific sequence of files included or processed is: F:\...\confirmDelete.cfm, line: 20 
6/25/2014   0:36:16     '' The specific sequence of files included or processed is: '''' 
6/25/2014   0:52:36     File not found: /.../List.cfm The specific sequence of files included or processed is: F:\...\List.cfm'' 


6/26/2014   3:57:29     Variable FACILITYDSN is undefined. The specific sequence of files included or processed is: F:\...\Default.cfm, line: 1 
6/26/2014   5:35:14     '' The specific sequence of files included or processed is: '''' 
6/26/2014   5:38:33     Error Executing Database Query.[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Invalid column name 'undefined'. The specific sequence of files included or processed is: F:\...\tabHolder.cfm, line: 4 


6/29/2014   5:11:30     The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: cfldap The specific sequence of files included or processed is: F:\...\EDCertNotifyDrivers.cfm, line: 186 
6/29/2014   5:52:01     The value --1 cannot be converted to a number. The specific sequence of files included or processed is: F:\...\dailyVacationReport.cfm, line: 350 
6/29/2014   9:51:26     '' The specific sequence of files included or processed is: '''' 
6/29/2014   13:12:28    '' The specific sequence of files included or processed is: '''' 
6/29/2014   16:48:00    '' The specific sequence of files included or processed is: '''' 
6/29/2014   18:13:18    File not found: /.../ReqLabView.cfm The specific sequence of files included or processed is: F:\...\ReqLabView.cfm'' 
6/29/2014   18:30:01    '' The specific sequence of files included or processed is: '''' 
6/29/2014   18:55:47    Element TOTALATTACH is undefined in COUNTATTACH. The specific sequence of files included or processed is: F:\...\CompleteJob.cfm, line: 386 


7/2/2014    10:07:22    Variable PLAINDATENOWNOW is undefined. The specific sequence of files included or processed is: F:\...\UpdateRecordAction.cfm, line: 281 
7/2/2014    11:09:00    '' The specific sequence of files included or processed is: '''' 
7/2/2014    13:18:06    Element SQL is undefined in CFCATCH. The specific sequence of files included or processed is: F:\...\SaveInst_OtherMatrix.cfm, line: 130
```

Please let me know if you need anymore info

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you running? What operating system are you running it on? What JVM version are you running? These may all be pertinent bits of information. Can you please include an actual excerpt of your application.log as well. Not the whole file but at least a few lines. That message is typically preceeded or followed with more information.

Comment: Look at your http log and see what pages were running at about that time.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything unusual in the http log at the same time these messages occur, just things like HTTP request completed around the same time but never the exact same time and never the exact same message so no pattern that I can see there.

Comment: Anything in the exception.log?

Comment: Ok there are errors in the log that match the times. I'm not sure if you would need to see the whole thing.  The ones I see are all identical except for the number at the front, they start out like this: Error,"ajp-bio-8012-exec-3225","07/07/14","07:59:20",,"'' The specific sequence of files included or processed is: '''' " 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 
 at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
 at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.getRealPathFromServer(AjpProcessor.java:390)
 at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.getRealPath(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:1112)

Comment: *not sure if you would need to see the whole thing* Maybe. Anything in the rest of the trace that gives an indication of the code or script that caused the exception? If yes, update your question to include the full trace.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is anything specific in the error traces, just a lot of stuff like above that makes not much sense to us :)  I think we are going to let this one go since no one seems to be complaining about issues related to this error.  Maybe it's not even an error - but a message - who knows!  We are going to focus on cleaning up the errors we can figure out first.  Thanks for trying to help!